# How to cut each word in a file

Tags: regex, perl, unix, cut

Is there a command which can turn a tab delimited file to give just the first 4 letters of each word?

Eg. Turning this file

```
Jackal Poorest Kingship Twinkle
Viscount George Lizard
Stone Goose Elephant Yvonne Chicken
Gecko Amoeba
Richard
```

To this file

```
Jack Poor King Twin
Visc Geor Liza
Ston Goos Elep Yvon Chic
Geck Amoe
Rich
```

Thanks

Comment: which language are you trying to code this in?

Comment: Unix or perl (one-liner) preferably.

Comment: I've tried the different cut syntaxes and all I can seem to do is split into columns, cut-c1-4 individually and paste, however this is very inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr` to trim each word.  Name the following `trim.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @words = split /\s+/;
    my @trim;
    for my $word (@words) {
        push @trim, substr($word,0,4);
    }
    print join ' ', @trim;
    print "\n";
}
```

Run it as:

```
cat names.txt | trim.pl
```

Which outputs:

```
Jack Poor King Twin
Visc Geor Liza
Ston Goos Elep Yvon Chic
Geck Amoe
Rich
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Pattern matching enough for to do it

```
while(<DATA>)
{
(@ar) = $_ =~m/(.{4}).+?\s/g;
print "@ar\n";
}
__DATA__
Jackal Poorest Kingship Twinkle
Viscount George Lizard
Stone Goose Elephant Yvonne Chicken
Gecko Amoeba
Richard

output
Jack Poor King Twin
Visc Geor Liza
Ston Goos Elep Yvon Chic
Geck Amoe
Rich
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane '$,=" "; print map substr($_,0,4),@F' input
```

Comment: Some explanation to go with the code would make it a better answer.

Comment: Yes, but it would also steal from the reader the joy of figuring it out!

Comment: Well, the explanation should be short enough to arouse interest and long enough to cover the subject; like a skirt :)

Answer (score 1):

Perl from command line,

```
perl -anE 'say join " ", map /(.{1,4})/, @F' file.txt
```

or

```
use feature 'say';

while (my $line = <>) {
  my @F = split ' ', $line;
  say join " ", map /(.{1,4})/, @F; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more readable awk version

```
awk '{l=sep=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){l = l sep substr($i,1,4); sep=FS}; print l}'
```

Comment: without any explanation and naming variables with L, I wouldn't call this readable.